An Inquiry into the Properties of Injective Modules within Module Theory
Let $I$ be a left module over a ring with unity $R$. If for any exact sequence
$$0 \to X \to Y \to Z \to 0$$
in the category of $R$-modules, we can get the following exact sequence in the category of abelian groups:
$$0 \to \text{Hom}_R(Z,I) \to \text{Hom}_R(Y,I) \to \text{Hom}_R(X,I) \to 0 \quad (*),$$
then we can conclude that $I$ is an injective module.
Now the question arises:
If for any exact sequence of finitely generated $R$-modules
$$0 \to X \to Y \to Z \to 0,$$
i.e., $X, Y, Z$ are finitely generated modules over $R$, we can also get that $(*)$ is exact, then can we also conclude that $I$ is injective?
If $R$ is a left Noetherian ring, by Baer's criterion, we can conclude that $I$ is injective when the above condition is satisfied. What about non-left Noetherian rings?

This is the case if and only if $R$ is left Noetherian.
A ring $R$ is left Noetherian if and only if every infinite direct sum of injective left modules is injective. This is the Bass-Papp theorem.
Suppose $I=\bigoplus_{i\in I}I_i$ is a direct sum of injective modules that is not itself injective, and that $0\to X\to Y\to Z\to0$ is a short exact sequence of finitely-generated modules.
For any map $\alpha:X\to I$, $\operatorname{im}\alpha\subseteq \bigoplus_{j\in J}I_j$ for some finite subset $J\subseteq I$, since $X$ is finitely-generated.
$\bigoplus_{j\in J}I_j$ is injective, since it is a finite direct sum of injective modules, and so $\alpha$ extends to a map $\beta:Y\to \bigoplus_{j\in J}I_j$

I greatly appreciate your response. I have comprehended the proof you provided.
